# Get values from string using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string like this:-

`var src=url("http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png)"`

And now I want to get image name i.e `black6.png` and folder name `6`.
I know there is `substr` function I can use but the file name and folder name will be dynamic like
`orange12.png` and `12` etc.

How I can get these values? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `var src="url('http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png')"`? What have you tried?

Comment: do you have any pattern for filename / foldername? what is constant about those two?

Comment: Do you mean the string value include the `var src=` part? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I know you have asked about how to learn C#, but I'm unable to answer your question in time because it had been deleted. I will answer you here. Read my another post at: http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/813176/tips-to-be-good-programmer-in-csharp-and-asp-net#answer1

Comment: @mjb thanks for reply yes I delete as that was closed by people with many downvotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the base URL is always the same you could do

```
var url = "http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png";
var bits = url.replace("http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/", "").split("/");
var folder = bits[0], // 6
    file = bits[1];  // black6.png
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method for this:

```
var src = "http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png";
var parsed = src.split( '/' );
console.log( parsed[ parsed.length - 1 ] ); // black6.png
console.log( parsed[ parsed.length - 2 ] ); // 6
console.log( parsed[ parsed.length - 3 ] ); // eyecatcher
```

etc.

Comment: FYI it should be `parsed.length -1` to get the image name, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If your string is:

```
var src="http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png"
```

Use the following:

```
var parts = src.split('/');
var img = parts.pop(); //black6.png
var flder = parts.pop(); //6
var sflder = parts.pop(); //eveatcher
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
var str = myString.split('/');
var answer = str[str.length - 1];
var answer1 = str[str.length - 2];
var answer2 = str[str.length - 3];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var img_name = src.split('/')[7];
var folder_name = src.split('/')[6];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `split` & `slice`, Say like bellow

```
var src = "http://localhost:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png";
var arr = src.split('/').slice(-2) //returns ["6", "black6.png"]
arr[0] //folderName
arr[1] //filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "http://MachineName:200/assets/images/eyecatcher/6/black6.png";

var newStr = str.split("/");  

ubound = newStr.length;

fileName = newStr[ubound-1];
```